# Metadata of audio file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, taglib

hi all i am extracting metadata of an audio file using Taglib library . i am getting many fields properly but not able to extract name of source device by which the audio file has been created. Please suggest any way to get out of it. Code used is as below

```
 MetaData md;

    const char * filename = file.c_str();
    std::cout<< filename;

    FileRef f((FileName(filename))); 

    md.filepath = file;
   //if(f.isNull()) return md;
   // if(!f.tag()) return md;
   // if(f.tag()->isEmpty()) return md;

    string artist = f.tag()->artist().toCString();
    string album = f.tag()->album().toCString();
    string title = f.tag()->title().toCString();//.to8Bit(true);
    uint year = f.tag()->year();
    uint track = f.tag()->track();
    int bitrate = f.audioProperties()->bitrate();
    string comment=f.tag()->comment().toCString();
    string genre =f.tag()->genre().toCString();
    // length in second  
    int lenght=f.file()->audioProperties()->length();

    int channel = f.file()->audioProperties()->channels();
    string name =f.file()->name();
    int sampleRate=f.audioProperties()->sampleRate();
```

Comment: We don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: MetaData md;
   
    const char * filename = file.c_str();
    std::cout<< filename;
  
 FileRef f((FileName(filename))); 
   
    md.filepath = file;
   //if(f.isNull()) return md;
   // if(!f.tag()) return md;
   // if(f.tag()->isEmpty()) return md;

 string artist = f.tag()->artist().toCString();
    string album = f.tag()->album().toCString();
    string title = f.tag()->title().toCString()

Comment: Edit your question and place the code there, with correct formatting.

Comment: @AustinHenley Couldyou please help me now ?? i am looking for the device name ?? thanks in advance

Comment: I am still searching for your kind response ?? Nobody is even looking on the post :(

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "name of source device by which the audio file has been created"? Are you looking for the name of the person or organisation that encoded the audio file, normally saved in the TENC tag?

Could you give us an example, what you want to see?